# Multiple subnets, multiple DHCP servers, 3 access points, no VLAN

Tags: switch, vlan, local-area-network

Good day folks,

I was working at a customer site which has an odd network setup.

The WAN connection is connected to an 8 port dumb switch.  The WAN modem provides DHCP for the 192.168.2.0/24 network.

In addition, it has 2 access points (Cisco Linksys WRT160N-V2) with different SSIDs on its subnet 192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.100.0/24.  Both are running DHCP servers providing addresses in their own subnet range.

There are no VLANs on this network to separate the different subnets.

So, in summary, there are 3 networks, 2 AP and 3 DHCP servers and no VLANs.

I've browsed through many previous postings here, and also on Google regarding a setup similar to this.  Most suggest that this solution works, and it does, but others suggest issues with it, with broadcast flooding(?)

I know that the setup can be made better with the setup of VLANs, but I am not interested in pursuing this discussion here.

What I would like some feedback on is does this setup cause congestion on the network - why, and how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This setup is dumb, but probably fine.

The access points are likely running NAT as well as DHCP. You could flatten this out by disabling both NAT and DHCP, in essence converting them from routers to switches. The gains are small, but can give you some granularity rather than having to treat all clients on an access point the same.

Either way, make sure that the access points aren't operating on interfering channels. Channels 1, 6 and 11 are all clear of each other.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts.  I suspected it to be the case and we ended up flattening the network, turning off NAT and DHCP on the APs.